# How to determine the frequency of skimage.filter.gabor function?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, scikit-image

I am now trying to use garbor function provided in skimage, the documentation is [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.gabor), there is a parameter called frequency for this function, but how to determine the frequency, in the documentation, the frequency is described as "Spatial frequency of the harmonic function", but how to compute this value? Is there any module which provides the function like this?

Comment: What you mean? This is a parameter; it is up to the user to define it. You can should whatever suits you needs.

Comment: Just don't know how to determine the frequency to get better performance...@Berriel

Comment: It really depends on the task you wanna solve. The question as is does not have enough info for anyone to jump in and help.

Comment: well...thx anyway